# MSAccess: list last date paid and sum of all payments

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are 2 tables:  TestService and TestPayment, related by ServiceID.  The contents of these 2 tables are:
[image]

In all there are 3 services and 3 Fees.  Each service has multiple payments associated with it; Service 1111 has 2 payments, Service 1112 has 3 payments and Service 1113 has 3 payments.  Each payment has an associated DatePaid.

I want a query to show:

1. For each service, the sum of total payments received for that service, AND the date of the last payment made for that service

To do this I created 3 queries:

1. TestQPaymentByVHC#:  This sums all the payments for each ServiceID
2. TestQLastInsPayment:   This retrieves the date of the last payment for each ServiceID
3. TestQCPA:  This should list all ServiceID’s (one record per ServiceID) with the sum of all payments received (From TestQPaymentByVHC#) and the date of the last payment received for each ServiceID (From TestQLastInsPayment)

Here is the problem:

If TestQLastInsPayment is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 TestPayment.ServiceID, Last(TestPayment.DatePaid) AS LastOfDatePaid, TestPayment.Amount
FROM TestPayment RIGHT JOIN TestService ON TestPayment.ServiceID = TestService.ServiceID
GROUP BY TestPayment.ServiceID, TestPayment.Amount
ORDER BY Last(TestPayment.DatePaid) DESC;
```

Then TestQCPA lists the date of the last payment for each ServiceID  ONLY for ONE of the ServiceID’s:

[image]

If I change TestQLastInsPayment to:

```
SELECT TestPayment.ServiceID, Last(TestPayment.DatePaid) AS LastOfDatePaid, TestPayment.Amount
FROM TestPayment RIGHT JOIN TestService ON TestPayment.ServiceID = TestService.ServiceID
GROUP BY TestPayment.ServiceID, TestPayment.Amount
ORDER BY Last(TestPayment.DatePaid) DESC;
```

Then TestQCPA lists all dates of payment for each Service ID and each date a payment was received, and it duplicates records for each ServiceID  such that each ServiceID is listed multiple times, one record for each date that a payment was received:
[image]

I am doing all this in the GUI and posting the SQL code.

How can I get TestQCPA to list ONLY one line per ServiceID, with the sum of all payments received for that ServiceID, but still have the DatePaid show the last date of payment for each ServiceID?

Comment: Do not group by amount, so only:   `GROUP BY TestPayment.ServiceID`

Comment: Don't quite understand. You want a single query to show "For each service, the sum of total payments received for that service, AND the date of the last payment made for that service". A single query to do this makes sense. What I don't understand is why the other 3 queries if you just need that first query.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the request, the below query should provide the requested information.  Max is used instead of last due to how access stores dates as seconds since 00:00:00 1/1/1900.

> SELECT TestPayment.ServiceID, Max(TestPayment.DatePaid) AS MaxOfDatePaid, Sum(TestPayment.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
> FROM TestPayment INNER JOIN TestService ON TestPayment.ServiceID = TestService.ServiceID
> GROUP BY TestPayment.ServiceID
> ORDER BY Max(TestPayment.DatePaid);

Comment: this query joins with TestService but does not use anything from TestService

Answer (score 0):

To include all the fields in your question:

```
SELECT svc.CPT, svc.Units, svc.Fee, svc.[Patient#], sum(pmt.amount) as [Sum of Amount Paid], max(pmt.datepaid) as [Date of Last Receipt], svc.serviceid
FROM testservice AS svc LEFT JOIN testpayment AS pmt ON svc.serviceid = pmt.serviceid
GROUP BY svc.serviceid, svc.CPT, svc.Units, svc.Fee, svc.[Patient#]
```

The LEFT JOIN is used because I assume that it is possible that TestService will contain a service for which no payments have yet been received and you said you want to see "*for each service*, the sum of total payments received for that service".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all tips. Turns out problem was I was using LAST(DatePaid).  Access does not seem to like LAST function with dates.  When I changed to MAX(DatePaid) it all worked.